# How to increment a specific week day by one in php?

Tags: php

Let's say I have a variable `$day`. It can be anything from `Monday` to `Sunday`. How could I use that `$day` variable and increment it by `1 day`?

Let's say, I have `$day = "Friday"`. How do I increment it to a `Saturday`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) adding '+1 day' to your string:

```
<?php
$day = "friday";
$day = date('D',strtotime($day.'+1 day'));
echo $day; // "Saturday"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array. There is little chances that weekdays will ever change in the near future (sarcastic)

```
// $weekday can be a string or a numeric value (1=Monday, 0,7=Sunday)
function getNextDayOfWeek($weekday, $count = 1) {
    static $weekdays = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');

    if (!is_numeric($weekday)) {
        $weekday = (int) array_search(ucfirst(strtolower($weekday)), $weekdays);
    }
    // make $count positive!
    if ($count < 0) $count = ($count % -7) + 7;

    return $weekdays[($weekday + $count) % 7];
}
```

If you're worried about localization, just have translation arrays :)

```
$weekdays_fr = array('Monday' => 'lundi', 'Tuesday' => 'mardi', ...);

$nextDay_fr = $weekdays_fr[getNextDayOfWeek('Friday')];  //= 'samedi'
```

** **Edit** **

Here is another way using built-in PHP functions, but I'd still prefer an array solution.

```
$weekday = 'Friday';

$nextDay = strftime('%A', strtotime("{$weekday} +1 day"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly clean solution, without using an array:

```
$day = "Monday"
$NextDay = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($day));
echo date("l", $NextDay);
```

Combined Solution:

```
$day = "Monday";
echo date("l", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($day)));
```

Keep in mind, `strtotime("Monday")` will return the next monday from the current date.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use an array for that:

```
$your_integer = 10;
$weekdays = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
print($weekdays[$your_integer % 7]);
```

By incrementing `$your_integer`, you will loop through the `$weekdays`-array; the modulo operation (`%`) keeps you within the correct range, so 10 % 7 will yield 3, thus the output will be Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit simpler to use repeatedly:

```
$nextday = array(
    "Monday" => "Tuesday",
    "Tuesday" => "Wednesday",
    "Wednesday" => "Thursday",
    "Thursday" => "Friday",
    "Friday" => "Saturday",
    "Saturday" => "Sunday",
    "Sunday" => "Monday",
);

$day = $nextday[$day];
```

Comment: what if the requirement changes and the user wants 2 days from any given day?

Comment: @YanickRochon Then we have little hope. Your answer would be better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Good exercise in thought on rotating patterns in arrays, but just in case you're trying to replicate time functions, don't. PHP has a neat **strtotime()** one that does wonders.

```
$ts = strtotime( "+3 day", strtotime("December 30, 2007"));
echo date("r", $ts );
```

That gives you:

`Wed, 02 Jan 2008 00:00:00 -0500`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use an array. But this would work too.

```
$day = "Friday";
$next_day = date('l', strtotime("{$day} +1 DAY"));
```

Answer (score 0):

see [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [strftime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

```
$time = strtotime(<your_date_as_a_string>) + (60*60*12); // seconds in 12 hours
$date = strftime(<format_you want>, $time); // or date(<same params>)
```